# loadJSON convert boolean to true or false from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am loading boolean data from mySql. the db is 0 or 1.  However JSON wants true or false for a form to load properly. I have 30 fields in the actual table. And yes I can convert the 0 1 to true false in the select using a case statement. But there must be an easier way to do this?

I have lots of boolean fields in the actual production. Maybe JSON doesn't handle this and only handles plain type="text"?

Otherwise I can load it all with PHP and set the values on load

Here is the original JSON

```
[{"drscomplete":"0"}]
```

and this is what I need for the checkbox to work properly on a form

```
[{"drscomplete":"true"}]
```

Here is the load php

```
$SQL ="SELECT * from dealfinalize d where d.ID=" . $id;

  $resultArray = array();

  $result = mysqli_query($con,$SQL);

    if($result->num_rows >0 ) 
     $resultArray = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

echo json_encode($resultArray);

and here is the ajax

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "dealfinalizeload.php",
    data:'id='+id,
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){

            var data2 = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('div#white_content_dealfinalize').loadJSON(data2);

            alert(data);

    }, 
    error:function (){
        alert("Error loading tasks");
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can use mysql `case if` to convert `0` and `1` to `true` or `false` at database layer itself. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: maybe not what you aer looking for, but you can write function assume `getAsBoolean()` make it common (in shared file) that takes value from mysql (0 or 1) and return true or false, based on a simple if-statement, and use this method when serializing JSON, like `data['drscomplete'] = getAsBoolean($row['drscomplete'])`, you need to use this on fields you already know it should be boolean

Comment: I was trying to use a simple command the load the JSON - I added the ajax load above

Answer (score 1):

You can use case

```
   select t1.column1,
      case when t2.column == 1
        then 'true'
        else 'false'
      end OrderedAll
    from yourtable t1
```

Comment: I have lots of booleans in the production DB that needs to load. see the additional info above